# Weird error when instantiating template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template function:

```
template <std::size_t first, std::size_t last, typename T>
bool in_range(T& in)
{
    for(auto i = in.begin(); i!=in.end(); ++i)
        if(*i<first || *i>last)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

but when I try to use it as such:

```
std::vector<int> test;
test.push_back(1);
test.push_back(5);
test.push_back(6);

std::cout<<in_range<4,7>(test);
```

I get this weird error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'bool in_range(T&) [with long long unsigned int first = 4ull; long long unsigned int last = 7ull; T = std::vector<int>]':
main.cpp:31:34:   required from here
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: full build log: http://pastebin.com/Cwemq2Hk

Comment: Is that really the full error message?

Comment: That's part of the error message, saying where the error occurs. It will be either followed or preceded by a description of the error - could you post the complete message?

Comment: Compiled fine VC2010 and here http://ideone.com/yGh30

Comment: That IS the full error message! ( followed by some signed/unsigned warnings which I believe are unrelated ). I'm using GCC 4.7.0 if that helps

Comment: http://codepad.org/dXWf6Jpk - the problem is inside the `in_range` function, and not in the template itself. First write a working normal function, and THEN convert it into a template.

Comment: I just tried `hmjd`'s code with g++ 4.7.0 and it worked fine. I also got the signed/unsigned warnings. They are because you compare (signed `int`s from the vector with (unsigned) `size_t`s in `if(*i<first || *i>last)`.

Comment: @Agent_L i is of type T::iterator so *i is correct

Comment: @user1233963: I very much doubt that's the full error message - GCC's messages always include the error description itself as well as the template instantiation points. Please post the full error message.

Comment: @user1233963 then edit your question and post the working, statically typed version.

Comment: @MikeSeymour check my edit for a full build log

Comment: That's not an error at all - it's just telling you where the two warnings came from. I've no idea why it says "1 error" at the end, since it appears to have successfully compiled and linked the program.

Comment: @MikeSeymour it seems you're right, it does generate a working output file. Thanks

Comment: @user1233963: That is not an error message (where is the *error* word in there?), but rather a hint to the location of the next message from the compiler (in this case the warnings about the comparisons...)

Answer (score 2):

If I build that with C++11 support enabled, then it compiles. [Here is a demonstation](http://ideone.com/e4Qjh).

Before C++11, `auto` had a different meaning, and so `auto i = ...` was invalid - it declared a variable with no type.

I guess you're using GCC; depending on the version, you'll need to specify either `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` as a command-line option.

Comment: OK, in that case we'll need to know the compiler version, and it would help to have a complete, compilable example. Your code works for me: http://ideone.com/e4Qjh